# How to fix CSP error for Angular Stripe JS

Tags: javascript, angular, stripe-payments, content-security-policy

I'm using a pattern of code that's on MANY web pages as "the way to integrate Stripe Payment on your Angular Website. Here's an example page: [https://www.freakyjolly.com/stripe-payment-checkout-gateway-angular-tutorial/#:~:text=How%20to%20Integrate%20Stripe%20Payment%20Gateway%20in%20Angular%3F,HTML%20File%205%20Step%205%20%E2%80%93%20Run%20Application](https://www.freakyjolly.com/stripe-payment-checkout-gateway-angular-tutorial/#:%7E:text=How%20to%20Integrate%20Stripe%20Payment%20Gateway%20in%20Angular%3F,HTML%20File%205%20Step%205%20%E2%80%93%20Run%20Application)

You set up two functions:

```
  initializePayment(amount: number) {
    const paymentHandler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: 'pk_test_sLUqHXtqXOkwSdPosC8ZikQ800snMatYMb',
      locale: 'auto',
      token: function (stripeToken: any) {
        console.log({stripeToken})
        alert('Stripe token generated!');
      }
    });
  
    paymentHandler.open({
      name: 'FreakyJolly',
      description: 'Buying a Hot Coffee',
      amount: amount * 100
    });
  }
  
  invokeStripe() {
    if(!window.document.getElementById('stripe-script')) {
      const script = window.document.createElement("script");
      script.id = "stripe-script";
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = "https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js";
      script.onload = () => {
        this.paymentHandler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
          key: 'pk_test_sLUqHXtqXOkwSdPosC8ZikQ800snMatYMb',
          locale: 'auto',
          token: function (stripeToken: any) {
            console.log(stripeToken)
            alert('Payment has been successfull!');
          }
        });
      }
      window.document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
  }
```

Then call invokeStripe from ngOnInit(), and call initializePayment when the user clicks a button. Everything seems to work, but I get a nasty CSP error and nothing seems to make it go away!

> [Report Only] Refused to execute inline script because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'
> 'sha256-blah blah blah'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash
> ('sha256-some other blah blah'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required
> to enable inline execution.

How can I do a nonce for .ts inline? I tried adding a CSP to my *head* of that module, but that doesn't seem to help either.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
    content="
    default-src * 'self'; 
    script-src * 'self' https://checkout.stripe.com 'unsafe-inline'; 
    style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; 
    connect-src * 'self' https://checkout.stripe.com; 
    frame-src * 'self' https://checkout.stripe.com;
    img-src * 'self' https://*.stripe.com data:;
">
```

Comment: The link you are referring to uses something called Legacy Checkout which Stripe has actively deprecated multiple years ago. No new integration should build on top of that product as it's extremely limited (card only) and doesn't support new features like 3D Secure and such. Please do not follow this guide at all. Consider using newer Checkout instead: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout

Comment: Thanks. I believe the "new" checkout requires massive server-side overhaul. We simply can't afford it as a nonprofit just to use Stripe as an option to PayPal, which works in Angular. In the meantime, the legacy system does appear to still be active, and all we need is card support. Do you know the answer to my questions above? Thanks.

Comment: That's a misunderstanding honestly. The newer Checkout is drastically easier to implement compared to the old one, and both require a server. If you don't want to code, the easiest is to use PaymentLinks, they can even accept donations: https://stripe.com/en-de/payments/payment-links. I don't know the answer to your specific question. You should really not use a 4+ years old integration that is unmaintained, but if you want to, I'd load their script upfront in the head instead of dynamically like you do.

Comment: Loading upfront in a script gives the same error. Perhaps developers have just been ignoring it as it appears to still run and function. Not sure what you mean by "misunderstanding" as this approach works without requiring back-end code. And it's not that we want to avoid coding. It's that all of our other payment options work fine from from the UI (like paypal). Why would be want to break our architecture to add one more payment option and do a lot of one-off coding? The user experience becomes completely different that way and introduces new "what if this happens?"

Comment: Legacy Checkout creates a card Token `tok_123`, that's all. It never charges their card. You always need a server to accept a payment with it. And it's way easier to use the newer version of Checkout than this old one.